# Having some trouble with the OpenReport macro

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to filter a report using an on-click button in a form. The form has a text box called MemberName, and I would like the report opened from clicking the button to only show records where the report's MemberName is the same as the form's MemberName. I used the OpenReport macro with the following WHERE condition:

```
WHERE = [MemberName] = Reports![ReportABC]![MemberName]
```

However, the report shown after clicking the button shows blank records. How can I fix this? I know I can alternatively build parameter queries directly related to the report in order to filter it, but I would very much like to just filter the report by using command buttons. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to filter for a value on your form, so you need to refer to that. And WHERE is implied in the `WhereCondition` parameter, son don't include that.

It could look like this:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptMember", View:=acViewPreview, _
                 WhereCondition:="[MemberName] = Forms![yourForm]![MemberName]"
```